# WordPress generated thumbnail attributes show alt="{{alt}}" and title="{{title}}"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

How to fix WordPress generated image thumbnail attributes showing `alt="{{alt}}" and title="{{title}}"?`  on WooCommerce single product page `80x80` thumbnails using Enfold theme ?

Comment: alt="{{alt}}" and title="{{title}}" on WooCommerce single product page 80x80 thumbnails using Enfold theme

Comment: also used WooThumbs - Awesome Product Imagery plugin for hover zoom image effect